# Jinja2 Inheritance with Blocks and Includes

Tags: python, pyramid, jinja2

I can't figure out how to modify blocks from included templates using Jinja2. Here's an example where I use three files.

base.html:

```
<html>{% include "content.html" %}</html>
```

content.html:

```
<h1>{% block title %}Title{% endblock title%}</h1>
<div>{% block content_body %}Content Body{% endblock content_body%}</div>
```

story.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}story.title{% endblock title %}
{% block content_body %}story.description{% endblock content_body %}
```

When rendering story.html, I'll get:

```
<html>
<h1>Title</h1>
<div>Content Body</div>
</html>
```

How would I render with the expected values?

Comment: You should be looking at **macros** in Jinja2. I think this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104957/in-jinja2-how-can-i-use-macros-in-combination-with-block-tags) is related to your queries.

Comment: Where is @ArminRonacher when you need him - I have a feeling that this is caused by `include "content.html"` overriding the contents of the identically named blocks in `story` even though `story` is overriding `base` - but I don't see anything in the documentation to indicate that this is to be expected.

Answer (score 15):

`base.html` is not rendered because it's not invoked by any template. What you *could* do is a second level of extension:

base.html:

```
<html>{% block html %}{% endblock %}</html>
```

content.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block html %}
<h1>{% block title %}Title{% endblock title%}</h1>
<div>{% block content_body %}Content Body{% endblock content_body%}</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Still, that is probably overkill, you will likely find that a single base template is enough (i.e. combine `base.html` and `content.html` into a single template).

Comment: this is the proper solution for templates check django templates they do a similar thing to understand the concept.